# How can I use slide or fade toggle on dynamically created div elements

Tags: jquery

This is some part of the code I am confused on how can I make my div fade toggle.

```
            var tw="";
            for(var i=len-1;i>=0;i--){

                if(data3[i].ID==y){
                    tw+='<br><div id ="#cmnt'+data3[i].ID+'">';
            tw+='<img id="im" src="uploads/'+data3[i].photo+'" onerror=this.src="uploads/rr.jpg" style="width:30px;height:30px;">';
            tw+='<span id="nm" class="default_name">' + data3[i].usr +'      </span>         '+data3[i].date + '';
            tw+='<p class="pst">'+data3[i].cmnt+' <p></div>'; 
               $('#cmnt'+data3[i].ID).slideToggle();
                  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to append content of tw(display:none;) in to some div and then you can call 
`$('#somediv').append(tw);`

`$('#cmnt'+data3[i].ID).slideDown();`

to slide it in.

Comment: I tried it but it actually first slides in and then slides out  all in one click

Comment: Try calling slideDown instead of slideToggle.

Comment: I actually want to use toggle because on second click I want it to hide

Comment: It is sliding in and out simultaneously may be because of your loop because it might be calling slideToggle again.

Comment: Try moving your slideToggle line outside your for loop. Hope it helps.